# Do these sentences have the same meaning?

Tags: british-english, subcontinental-english

Please tell me if the following sentences have the same meaning or if there is any difference between them.

> 1. I can't do this task.
> 2. I didn't finish this task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I didn't finish this task

means you did only part of the task, not all of it.

> I can't do this task

either means the task is too difficult for you or there is some reason for you not to want to do it even though you are told to.

Comment: To be nitpicky, "I didn't finish this task" doesn't strictly mean that he did part of it. Maybe he didn't even *start* it.